# Typescript won't emit import statements as-is

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, ecmascript-next

My `index.html` imports only one script with `<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>`

And at the top of `index.ts` are the now-standard import statements

```js
import { PieChart } from "./pie-chart.js";
import { ChartLegend } from "./chart-legend.js";
```

But index.ts, when compiled to index.js, the import statements are completely removed, replaced with nothing else.  My `tsconfig.json` is set to

```
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ESNext",
```

But regardless if "module" is set to ES6, ES2015, ES2020, or ESNext, they all work the same.

Browsers now understand the import statement natively, and will import the files correctly (assuming .js extension is there and the path is correct). I tried this by copy-pasting those import statements into the resulting .js file and everything lights up.

How could / why can't Typescript (Version 4.0.2) emit the imports??

Comment: Are you compiling with `tsc` or some bundler such as webpack? What command are you using to compile?

Comment: TypeScript will elide unused imports, and imports used only in type positions by default

Comment: `tsc`, no bundler.  It was because the imports where just used in type positions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript drops imports from the file if the imported items are only used as types.

```js
import { PieChart } from "./pie-chart.js";

const pie = document.querySelector("pie-chart") as PieChart;
```

Will not cause the import to be emitted.  However, you can import a module "for its side effects" with

```js
import "./pie-chart.js";
```

and the import will be emitted. You can also do both.

```js
import { PieChart } from "./pie-chart.js";
import "./pie-chart.js";

const pie = document.querySelector("pie-chart") as PieChart;
```

But this may not scale well for an app of any significant size.